# @Scheduled annotation for specific time interval

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I want to schedule a job to run just for a month (configurable) every year and that should run every day at specific time (let's say everyday 01:00 AM UTC). Can we achieve this in springboot using @Schedule annotation? If not, what could be the best way to achieve that?
 I tried below

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 1/1 * ? *")
```

This runs everyday at 1 but I want it to start running on let's say 10th May and stop running on 10th June. That start and end time should be configurable so that I can change it later without code change

Comment: Did you try it? Annotate a method with the annotation and an appropriate trigger and see if it meets your purposes? "Best way" is opinion based.

Comment: I already tried. It does not work for my need as mentioned in question.

Comment: You didn't say that in the question. You asked if you could use it, and I am asking if you bothered trying since that's kind of, you know, the point of the annotation. If you tried it and it didn't "work for your needs," that's a different question esp. since we have no idea what your "needs" are.

Comment: You can define crontab as per your requirement
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")   
(second minute hour day month weekday)

Comment: updated question. @Roddy: if you read my question again, it starts with I WANT, which is my need

Comment: Your question *now* says what you tried and why it didn't work. In its earlier state it was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

One I would suggest is something like below:

```
public class Scheduler{

@Value("${your.start.date}")
private String startDate;

@Value("${your.end.date}")
private String endDate;

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 1/1 * ? *")
public void do()
{
    ZonedDateTime startDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(startDate);
    ZonedDateTime endDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(endDate);
    if(ZonedDateTime.now().isAfter(startDate) && ZonedDateTime.now().isBefore(endDate)){
        //do your job here
    }
    //do nothing if condition is not meet
}
```

}

Comment: This is just a work around on what I am looking for. I wanted to do exactly what you are doing but not writing the logic (if else condition)